# How to access intermediate layers in a pretrained model after retraining it on a new image dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I trained a VGG16 model on a labeled image dataset using the `categorical crossentropy`. I removed the fully connected layer and replaced it with new layers, as follows:

```
vgg16_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
model = Sequential()
model.add(vgg16_model)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(70, activation='softmax'))
```

Then I trained the full model on my dataset. I want to use it now as a feature extraction model by extracting image features using any of the intermediate layers that belong to `vgg16_model`.

After training and saving the model, I can only access the layers that I added `Dense` and `Dropout` using `pop()` function to remove them and only keep the trained feature extractor model (vgg16).

```
i = 0
while i < 4: 
    model.pop()
```

This keeps only `VGG16` model. However, the layers inside are not accessible, I tried:

```
new_model = Model(model.input,model.layers[-1].output)
```

But I get this error:

> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_9'), name='input_9', description="created by layer 'input_9'") at layer "block1_conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

How can I modify my model to consider early k layers at a given time, then use the model for prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the keras model in the way you did, unfortunately has many complications when we tried to features from intermediate layer. I've raised a ticket, see [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16355).

---

As you want to extract image features using any of the intermediate layers that belong to `vgg16_model`, you can try the following approach.

```
# [good practice]: check first to know name and shape
# for layer in model.layers:
#     print(layer.name, layer.output_shape)

# vgg16 (None, 7, 7, 512)
# flatten (None, 25088)
# dense (None, 256)
# dropout (None, 256)
# dense_1 (None, 70)
```

```
# get the trained model first
trained_vgg16 = keras.Model(
    inputs=model.get_layer(name="vgg16").inputs,
    outputs=model.get_layer(name="vgg16").outputs,
)

x = tf.ones((1, 224, 224, 3))
y = trained_vgg16(x)
y.shape
TensorShape([1, 7, 7, 512])
```

Next, use this `trained_vgg16` model to build the target model. For example,

```
# extract only 1 intermediate layer
feature_extractor_block3_pool = keras.Model(
    inputs=trained_vgg16.inputs,
    outputs=trained_vgg16.get_layer(name="block3_pool").output,
)

# or, 2 based on purpose.
feature_extractor_block3_pool_block4_conv3 = keras.Model(
    inputs=trained_vgg16.inputs,
    outputs=[
        trained_vgg16.get_layer(name="block3_pool").output,
        trained_vgg16.get_layer(name="block4_conv3").output,
    ],
)

# or, all
feature_extractor = keras.Model(
    inputs=trained_vgg16.inputs,
    outputs=[layer.output for layer in trained_vgg16.layers],
)
```